# pytorch softmax outputs several values

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, softmax

I'm trying to calculate the softmax to get the probability of the text being real or not.

When I use the openai weights and load the checkpoint for their detector I get the following results using the pytorch softmax function.

```
('fake', tensor([2.3000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 1.3380e+01, 5.1000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 9.0000e-01, 4.2000e-01,
    4.3000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.1000e-01,
    4.7000e-01, 1.2000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 5.3000e-01,
    6.1000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 3.8000e-01,
    4.6000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 5.2000e-01,
    0.0000e+00, 8.2000e-01, 9.0000e-01, 3.3000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 8.8000e-01,
    7.5000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 6.1000e-01,
    7.9000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 6.3000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 3.3000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 4.1000e-01,
    4.0000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 2.8000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 4.7000e-01,
    5.4000e-01, 2.9000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 3.9000e-01,
    4.1000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 3.8000e-01,
    3.6000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 3.6000e-01,
    4.4000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 4.0000e-01,
    4.7000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 6.5000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 2.6000e-01, 5.1000e-01,
    6.0000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 7.0000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 6.5000e-01,
    9.0000e-02, 4.3000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 0.0000e+00,
    3.3000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 2.8000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 7.0000e-01,
    5.5000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 6.5000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 5.8000e-01,
    6.9000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 2.6000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 8.3000e-01,
    4.0000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 6.3000e-01, 5.4000e-01,
    5.0000e-01, 7.1000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 4.1000e-01,
    6.6000e-01, 6.5000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 4.9000e-01,
    6.6000e-01, 7.7000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 3.2000e-01,
    3.2000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 3.1000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 1.1000e-01, 5.3000e-01,
    4.0000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 2.0000e-02,
    3.2000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 6.6000e-01,
    2.5000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 7.9000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 6.5000e-01,
    5.7000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.4000e-01,
    6.2000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 2.0000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 5.1000e-01,
    3.7000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 4.1000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 3.3000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 7.3000e-01, 6.1000e-01,
    5.7000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 7.9000e-01, 5.2000e-01,
    3.6000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 6.9000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 4.9000e-01,
    8.8000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 5.3000e-01,
    7.1000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 3.8600e+00, 5.2000e-01,
    4.0000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 6.6000e-01,
    5.7000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 7.5000e-01, 6.6000e-01, 6.2000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 8.2000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 7.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 7.7000e-01,
    4.2000e-01, 7.3000e-01, 6.2000e-01, 3.3000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 7.0000e-01,
    4.5000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 7.5000e-01,
    2.8000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 4.0000e-01,
    2.9000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 8.2000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 5.0000e-01,
    6.3000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 6.4000e-01,
    2.2000e-01, 2.5000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 6.9000e-01, 5.4000e-01,
    4.6000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.3000e-01, 4.7000e-01,
    7.2000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 7.7000e-01,
    5.7000e-01, 3.3000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.2000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 6.2000e-01,
    4.7000e-01, 2.9000e-01, 0.0000e+00, 3.0000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 5.6000e-01,
    6.4000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 3.5000e-01,
    4.0000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 4.8000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 6.7000e-01,
    6.5000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 8.5000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 3.4000e-01,
    4.1000e-01, 2.7000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 2.9000e-01,
    5.8000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 4.4000e-01,
    4.6000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 2.9000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 7.0000e-01, 5.2000e-01,
    4.1000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.0000e-02,
    4.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 4.5000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 8.7000e-01, 0.0000e+00, 4.7000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 8.3000e-01,
    3.3000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 3.7000e-01,
    5.3000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 9.1000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 4.5000e-01,
    7.7000e-01, 6.5000e-01, 6.7000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.6000e-01,
    6.5000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 6.2000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 3.3000e-01,
    3.2000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 3.0000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    6.9000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 2.9000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 3.1000e-01, 3.6000e-01,
    5.8000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.9000e-01,
    3.6000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 8.4000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 6.8000e-01,
    5.6000e-01, 6.7000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 6.2000e-01, 0.0000e+00, 3.5000e-01,
    6.5000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    5.5000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 0.0000e+00, 5.1000e-01,
    5.0000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 1.1500e+00, 4.7000e-01, 4.7000e-01,
    4.0000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 1.3000e-01, 6.5000e-01, 6.0000e-02,
    3.6000e-01, 2.7000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 2.7000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 5.4000e-01,
    5.6000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 6.4000e-01,
    4.2000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 7.6000e-01, 5.3000e-01,
    5.7000e-01, 3.3000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 1.5000e-01,
    5.9000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 3.3000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    3.3000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 4.5000e-01,
    5.4000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 2.9000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 0.0000e+00, 3.4000e-01,
    5.9000e-01, 7.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 6.9000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 2.0000e-02,
    3.6000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 6.8000e-01,
    5.0000e-01, 3.0000e-01, 2.8000e-01, 3.0000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 4.2000e-01,
    6.2000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 5.7000e-01,
    6.1000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 3.0000e-01, 3.7000e-01,
    2.2000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 4.3000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 6.9000e-01, 6.7000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 6.1000e-01,
    6.5000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 8.8000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 6.0000e-01,
    4.4000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 4.1000e-01,
    5.3000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 4.3000e-01,
    3.5000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 8.3000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    6.5000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 4.3000e-01,
    5.3000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.8000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 2.3000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 4.9000e-01,
    5.2000e-01, 7.2000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 5.6000e-01,
    5.4000e-01, 6.7000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 6.6000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    5.5000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 3.2000e-01,
    4.2000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 7.6000e-01,
    3.4000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 5.7000e-01,
    5.2000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 4.8000e-01,
    6.3000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 2.8000e-01,
    5.3000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 2.0000e-02, 2.9000e-01, 3.1000e-01,
    4.6000e-01, 3.4000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 1.6000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 5.9000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    3.7000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 3.5000e-01,
    6.7000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 6.4000e-01, 4.2000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 4.9000e-01,
    3.5000e-01, 3.8000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 3.9000e-01,
    3.8000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 3.8000e-01,
    5.5000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 3.6000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 6.0000e-01, 4.8000e-01,
    6.5000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 1.8000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 5.2000e-01,
    4.6000e-01, 2.8000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 4.1000e-01,
    5.1000e-01, 7.0000e-01, 4.3000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 5.2000e-01, 4.3000e-01,
    6.0000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 3.2000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 6.3000e-01, 4.7000e-01,
    4.2000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 3.5000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 3.1000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 1.0000e-02, 8.4000e-01, 5.4000e-01, 3.0000e-01, 3.4000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 3.0000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 5.0000e-01,
    5.4000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 3.7000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 4.4000e-01, 4.7000e-01,
    7.1000e-01, 8.4000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 2.7000e-01, 5.6000e-01,
    4.7000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 5.5000e-01, 4.8000e-01, 7.4000e-01, 4.2000e-01,
    5.3000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 4.5000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 7.0000e-01,
    3.8000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 5.6000e-01, 5.8000e-01, 5.0000e-01, 6.1000e-01,
    3.7000e-01, 2.6000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 5.1000e-01, 5.7000e-01, 3.9000e-01,
    4.8000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 4.7000e-01, 5.3000e-01,
    3.4000e-01, 6.8000e-01, 6.1000e-01, 4.6000e-01, 4.0000e-01, 4.6000e-01,
    1.3000e-01, 4.1000e-01, 4.9000e-01, 3.9000e-01, 5.3000e-01, 4.5000e-01])
```

When I use my custom weights and parameters of my fine-tuned gpt2 model I get similar output:

```
('fake', tensor([0.2400, 0.3700, 0.2300, 0.6100, 0.4700, 0.3400, 0.0000, 0.3500, 0.3900,
    0.3800, 0.6100, 0.4200, 0.3100, 0.5600, 0.7200, 0.6100, 0.5900, 0.3200,
    0.2700, 0.3700, 0.4700, 0.3400, 0.4100, 0.6300, 0.5900, 0.5700, 0.5700,
    0.3600, 0.6400, 0.4000, 0.5900, 0.4100, 0.3400, 0.4700, 0.4100, 0.3400,
    0.0000, 0.5700, 0.5700, 0.2300, 0.5800, 0.4800, 0.5900, 0.4800, 0.4600,
    0.5500, 0.4500, 0.3900, 0.6300, 0.2700, 0.4200, 0.5000, 0.4100, 0.4000,
    0.5000, 0.2900, 0.4500, 0.3600, 0.4500, 0.5100, 0.4000, 0.5700, 0.4000,
    0.4000, 0.6000, 0.4800, 0.4800, 0.2200, 0.5000, 0.4000, 0.3200, 0.4500,
    0.3600, 0.5300, 0.6600, 0.4600, 0.4200, 0.0200, 0.3100, 0.5100, 0.2800,
    0.3700, 0.6600, 0.4100, 0.5700, 0.5600, 0.1400, 0.5900, 0.4900, 0.3200,
    0.3200, 0.3600, 0.2900, 0.3200, 0.5500, 0.4800, 0.3200, 0.7400, 0.3900,
    0.5900, 0.5600, 0.6800, 0.4100, 0.3400, 0.4900, 0.3700, 0.3900, 0.0000,
    0.3900, 0.4400, 0.4200, 0.8900, 0.2900, 0.5200, 0.3100, 0.3500, 0.7400,
    0.1400, 0.3100, 0.9700, 0.5300, 0.2700, 0.3000, 0.4500, 0.6500, 0.3900,
    0.2700, 0.5100, 0.3000, 0.4900, 0.5700, 0.7500, 0.5400, 0.6100, 0.7100,
    0.7000, 0.4600, 0.4300, 0.6000, 0.2600, 0.4100, 0.5500, 0.0100, 0.6900,
    0.6600, 0.0100, 0.3800, 0.5300, 0.3900, 0.3300, 0.4900, 0.5200, 0.4300,
    0.3300, 0.2800, 0.3400, 0.4900, 0.4200, 0.3700, 0.5000, 0.8500, 0.5800,
    0.5100, 0.7100, 0.3900, 0.7700, 0.5600, 0.9300, 0.3400, 0.5500, 0.4500,
    0.5400, 0.4600, 0.5400, 0.4000, 0.4300, 0.4700, 0.3400, 0.5300, 0.6200,
    0.3700, 0.4400, 0.5100, 0.4300, 0.5500, 0.4100, 0.5900, 0.3600, 0.5200,
    0.5700, 0.6200, 0.8100, 0.4600, 0.4000, 0.3900, 0.6000, 0.6400, 0.6100,
    0.3200, 0.4600, 0.3400, 0.3600, 0.6900, 0.5200, 0.3900, 0.4000, 0.3900,
    0.4500, 0.5800, 0.5400, 0.5800, 0.5900, 0.4900, 0.3100, 0.7600, 0.5700,
    0.5200, 0.5000, 0.5500, 0.3600, 0.4100, 0.3900, 0.4600, 0.3100, 0.2100,
    0.4500, 0.5300, 0.4900, 0.7200, 0.3900, 0.2800, 0.5800, 0.0000, 0.4800,
    0.4400, 0.2900, 0.4000, 0.5000, 0.3600, 0.4400, 0.4400, 0.2700, 0.5000,
    0.6000, 0.7800, 0.5400, 0.4200, 0.4700, 0.6200, 0.7000, 0.3900, 0.4000,
    0.5700, 0.5600, 0.3200, 0.7000, 0.6100, 0.5600, 0.4200, 0.4000, 0.3700,
    0.3100, 0.4300, 0.8100, 0.4200, 0.3100, 0.5900, 0.4100, 0.5400, 0.2500,
    0.5000, 0.0200, 0.3400, 0.3900, 0.3700, 0.4300, 0.3500, 0.3200, 0.4500,
    0.6000, 0.4100, 0.3600, 0.4500, 0.4100, 0.6400, 0.3600, 0.4200, 0.4600,
    0.2100, 0.1900, 0.8700, 0.5300, 0.4800, 0.4100, 0.6100, 0.3200, 0.4300,
    0.5400, 0.5200, 0.2800, 0.4400, 0.4700, 0.3400, 0.4000, 0.6100, 0.7400,
    0.5500, 0.4000, 0.2700, 0.3700, 0.3700, 0.4400, 0.4200, 0.5200, 0.0000,
    0.4600, 0.2700, 0.5500, 0.6200, 0.5800, 0.5400, 0.3300, 0.3200, 0.4600,
    0.3900, 0.4100, 0.2900, 0.5900, 0.5600, 0.4200, 0.4200, 0.6600, 0.4900,
    0.4200, 0.5000, 0.5000, 1.0200, 0.4200, 0.5000, 0.6300, 0.6700, 0.4400,
    0.3700, 0.3600, 0.3000, 0.4200, 0.5600, 0.2900, 0.5100, 0.5700, 0.4500,
    0.4300, 0.5300, 0.4300, 0.3000, 0.6300, 0.3000, 0.5100, 0.5100, 0.5100,
    0.5200, 0.2000, 0.0500, 0.3400, 0.4200, 0.1200, 0.6500, 0.5200, 0.4100,
    0.7100, 0.4900, 0.3900, 0.4100, 0.7700, 0.0000, 0.5700, 0.4800, 0.1800,
    0.2100, 0.5400, 0.3600, 0.4500, 0.7600, 0.2400, 0.3800, 0.5600, 0.5800,
    0.6400, 0.7000, 0.0300, 0.5700, 0.5700, 0.6100, 0.3800, 0.5100, 0.6200,
    0.5100, 0.5700, 0.8100, 0.4400, 0.5000, 0.3400, 0.2100, 0.4100, 0.4500,
    0.5700, 0.3600, 0.3700, 0.0300, 0.3200, 0.3000, 0.5100, 0.3800, 0.4400,
    0.3700, 0.2500, 0.3900, 0.7200, 0.3600, 0.5500, 0.4900, 0.6000, 0.8900,
    0.4400, 0.4400, 0.4900, 0.5900, 0.4400, 0.6900, 0.3400, 0.0000, 0.3500,
    0.6300, 0.5400, 0.5300, 0.3500, 0.5400, 0.3200, 0.4300, 0.4500, 0.4100,
    0.3100, 0.0000, 0.5400, 0.5400, 0.5000, 0.3600, 1.2000, 0.4500, 0.3200,
    0.3500, 0.4200, 0.5600, 0.2400, 0.4300, 0.2400, 0.5800, 0.3900, 0.4900,
    0.1300, 0.4300, 0.5300, 0.4200, 0.3600, 0.6700, 0.3300, 0.3700, 0.4600,
    0.3300, 0.2400, 0.5000, 0.5100, 0.4300, 0.4300, 0.4900, 0.3700, 0.6100,
    0.3600, 0.5100, 0.1600, 0.5900, 0.4100, 0.3300, 0.3500, 0.5200, 0.4600,
    0.3800, 0.4500, 0.3400, 0.4400, 0.4900, 0.5100, 0.4900, 0.3700, 0.3900,
    0.4300, 0.0000, 0.3100, 0.6400, 0.5300, 0.3300, 0.5300, 0.4400, 0.0500,
    0.3500, 0.4500, 0.5100, 0.3900, 0.4300, 0.5700, 0.6500, 0.5200, 0.3700,
    0.3000, 0.2800, 0.3900, 0.4800, 0.2000, 0.4900, 0.3100, 0.6400, 0.4500,
    0.5100, 0.5400, 0.3200, 0.1400, 0.6300, 0.2900, 0.2600, 0.3300, 0.4100,
    0.3900, 0.3900, 0.6400, 0.4500, 0.6400, 0.4500, 0.3500, 0.3900, 0.5500,
    0.4700, 0.4700, 0.3800, 0.4100, 0.4000, 0.4000, 0.5800, 0.4000, 0.4600,
    0.4400, 0.8700, 0.0000, 0.5500, 0.5200, 0.2200, 0.5300, 0.5500, 0.4900,
    0.5100, 0.4700, 0.5000, 0.6400, 0.5300, 0.5800, 0.6000, 0.2700, 0.3000,
    0.5800, 0.5000, 0.4400, 0.2400, 0.4700, 0.4300, 0.4000, 0.5600, 0.4200,
    0.5100, 0.5000, 0.4400, 0.3200, 0.5100, 0.4900, 0.4200, 0.6900, 0.3800,
    0.4700, 0.4100, 0.5400, 0.5000, 0.6300, 0.6300, 0.4500, 0.5400, 0.5000,
    0.5000, 0.6400, 0.3800, 0.5800, 0.4900, 0.5100, 0.5300, 0.6000, 0.6100,
    0.4600, 0.3700, 0.6100, 0.3900, 0.5500, 0.2400, 0.6400, 0.7300, 0.3600,
    0.6700, 0.3600, 0.3700, 0.3700, 0.3100, 0.3200, 0.6500, 0.7200, 0.4600,
    0.3500, 0.6100, 0.3500, 0.4500, 0.5900, 0.4100, 0.0400, 0.3100, 0.3200,
    0.4500, 0.4000, 0.5600, 0.5400, 0.5500, 1.3600, 0.4900, 0.5700, 0.5100,
    0.6400, 0.6300, 0.4400, 0.4100, 0.4000, 0.5900, 0.6600, 0.4200, 0.4200,
    0.4700, 0.4500, 0.5600, 0.1800, 0.3200, 0.5200, 0.5200, 0.3800, 0.6000,
    0.5000, 0.4600, 0.0200, 0.5300, 0.4000, 0.5600, 0.6100, 0.6000, 0.3200,
    0.3700, 0.4900, 0.2600, 0.5800, 0.4200, 0.6100, 0.5100, 0.5400, 0.2100,
    0.8000, 0.3200, 0.5700, 0.3900, 0.0000, 0.4900, 0.6600, 0.3600, 0.5600,
    0.7400, 0.5000, 0.3600, 0.4400, 0.3500, 0.4100, 0.3900, 0.4800, 0.3500,
    0.3400, 0.3900, 0.5800, 0.4100, 0.3900, 0.4700, 0.3000, 0.4100, 0.2300,
    0.3700, 0.0000, 0.5000, 0.4500, 0.1900, 0.3700, 0.4100, 0.6400, 0.5000,
    0.4200, 0.4800, 0.6500, 0.3600, 0.3400, 0.4100, 0.4100, 0.0100, 0.3500,
    0.2700, 0.8200, 0.7100, 0.3400, 0.2300, 0.3800, 0.2600, 0.6200, 0.6500,
    0.5300, 0.5200, 0.5700, 0.3100, 0.5400, 0.5700, 0.4600, 0.5200, 0.5300,
    0.4400, 0.3300, 0.4400, 0.4900, 0.3500, 0.4800, 0.4300, 0.0600, 0.6200,
    0.4400, 0.4800, 0.5800, 0.5000, 0.3100, 0.2800, 0.5100, 0.5400, 0.5200,
    0.3100, 0.3400, 0.6700, 0.4000, 0.3400, 0.4600, 0.0100, 0.5700, 0.4700,
    0.3900, 0.5400, 0.4100]
```

I don't understand what is causing this.

I expected outputs to be fake % and real % that equals to 1.

The code is:

```
def gpt_detector(query, onnx_path=ONNX_path):
start = time.time()

ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(onnx_path)

tokens_onnx = tokenizer.encode(query)

all_tokens = len(tokens_onnx)

tokens_onnx = tokens_onnx[:tokenizer.model_max_length - 2]
used_tokens = len(tokens_onnx)

input_ids_o = torch.tensor([tokenizer.bos_token_id] + tokens_onnx + [tokenizer.eos_token_id]).unsqueeze(0)
mask = torch.ones_like(input_ids_o)

with torch.no_grad():
    ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(input_ids_o)}
    logits_onnx = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
    #ipdb.set_trace()

    # logits = model(tokens.to(device), attention_mask=mask.to(device))[0]

    logits_onnx_t = torch.tensor(logits_onnx[0])
    probs_onnx = torch.softmax(logits_onnx_t, 1)
    #ipdb.set_trace()
    end = time.time()
total_time = np.round(end - start, decimals=2)
fake_onnx, real_onnx = probs_onnx[0][0], probs_onnx[0][1]

fake_onnx = np.round(fake_onnx*100, decimals=2)
real_onnx = np.round(real_onnx*100, decimals=2)

return "fake onnx ", fake_onnx, "real onnx ", real_onnx, "used tokens ", used_tokens, "total time ", total_time
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: The softmax function takes a vector as input and produces a vector with the same dimension as output. Since your softmax is taking a vector as input, the output is also a vector, with the same dimension, and this is expected.

Still, it's totally unclear what you are trying to do with the output logits of gpt2. What is the architecture for the fake detection? Do you want a single output that represent the predicted fake probability? If yes how are you fine-tuning gpt2 for this task without any output processing?

Comment: The fine-tuning happens in another step and the checkpoint is loaded and then exported into onnx inference.  I expect the inference to give a % of how real/fake it is. After debugging further I realized that it's not a softmax issue. Somehow when I try to use my own fine-tuned Roberta model that's exported to onnx, the inference outputs an array with several values while when using openai detector model weights, it gives me the correct expected probability. But I still don't understand why it would work with one but not the other or what the value from onnx means when there's many outputs.

Comment: The Roberta model is not a fake detector model, it's a transformer outputting raw hidden-states without any specific head on top, that's why the outputs are multi-dimensional. If you want it to use it as a detector, you have to change the architecture, i.e. you have to add a classification head. The openai detector model is a detector model with a different architecture than bert/roberta, with a classification head already included, that's why it has only a single output.

Comment: Also, in my first comment, I asked how you are fine-tuning the roberta model, this is important because if you train with a standard masked language modeling (MLM) objective, then you are most likely have a text-only dataset (and not a text classification dataset, i.e. text -> real/fake), so you are most likely not training the model to be a fake detector.